Use melt to transpose columns into rows w/ Pandas
I have a table formatted like this (with many more columns):



yr_mo
Sales
Transactions
Items
Shipping Cost
Tax




2024-0420
20
50
100
12
2


2024-03
10
25
50
6
1



This isn't a great way to view the data, since the data is more columns that what I put in above.
What I'd like to do is to transpose the data  so that the data looks like this:




2024-04
2024-03




Sales
20
10


Transactions
50
25


Items
100
50


Shipping Cost
12
6


Tax
2
1



With this format, the larger number of metrics will be much more readable in the format in which this information will be presented.
I've tried doing df.transpose() which sort of works, however I need the category names to be in the leftmost column. This seems to be the trickiest part of the exercise for me, as I'm not intimately familiar with many Python functions. A bit of research looks like panda's melt or wide_to_long functions may help, but I'm struggling to implement them.
Any help is greatly appreciated, thx!
(editing to show how my q is different from proposed duplicate question - I am not trying to just index a column, on top of the indexing I also need to transpose the data and add in a column with data labels.)

You likely need df.set_index('yr_mo').T

@mozway this gives nearly the exact same output for me as df.transpose(). Is there an additional function to keep column names and display them as row labels once transposed?

Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Figured it out! Just needed to add reset_index() after the T

@mozway final code was df_transposed = df.set_index('yr_mo').T.reset_index()

I see, yes in this case you need reset_index
